# Convert table with columns as level to hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert Oracle table with levels into Oracle hierarchy table.

Original table structure:

[image]

Needed table structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 1 THEN level_1
       WHEN 2 THEN level_2
       WHEN 3 THEN level_3
       WHEN 4 THEN level_4
       WHEN 5 THEN level_5
       END As value,
       PRIOR id As parent
FROM   table_name
START WITH level_2 IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR level_1 = level_1
AND    (  (PRIOR level_2 IS NULL AND level_2 IS NOT NULL AND level_3 IS NULL)
       OR (PRIOR level_2 = level_2 AND PRIOR level_3 IS NULL AND level_3 IS NOT NULL AND level_4 IS NULL)
       OR (PRIOR level_2 = level_2 AND PRIOR level_3 = level_3 AND PRIOR level_4 IS NULL AND level_4 IS NOT NULL AND level_5 IS NULL)
       OR (PRIOR level_2 = level_2 AND PRIOR level_3 = level_3 AND PRIOR level_4 = level_4 AND PRIOR level_5 IS NULL AND level_5 IS NOT NULL)
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, level_1, level_2, level_3, level_4, level_5) AS
SELECT 1, 'Fasteners', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Fasteners', 'Nails', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Fasteners', 'Nails', 'Nuts washers', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Fasteners', 'Nails', 'Nuts washers', 'Nuts', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Fasteners', 'Nails', 'Nuts washers', 'Nuts', 'Hex nuts' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Power tools', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Power tools', 'Power saws', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'Power tools', 'Power saws', 'Band saws', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Power tools', 'Power saws', 'Circular saws', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE | PARENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fasteners | *null* |
| 2 | Nails | 1 |
| 3 | Nuts washers | 2 |
| 4 | Nuts | 3 |
| 5 | Hex nuts | 4 |
| 11 | Power tools | *null* |
| 12 | Power saws | 11 |
| 13 | Band saws | 12 |
| 14 | Circular saws | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kEZWO36g)

Comment: Your query works just great!

I have tried to build a query by using NVL2, but it doesn't workout well.

SELECT
    id
    , NVL2(level_5, level_5, NVL2(level_4, level_4, NVL2(level_3, level_3, NVL2(level_2, level_2, level_1)))) name
    , NVL2(level_5, level_4, NVL2(level_4, level_3, NVL2(level_3, level_2, NVL2(level_2, level_1, level_1)))) parent_name
    , 1 parent_id
FROM product_categories_levels
;